# Strange "File does not exist" error

Tags: apache-2.2

The following URLs work well if I visit them with browsers.

- mydomain.com/f123
- mydomain.com/f123/
- www.mydomain.com/f123
- www.mydomain.com/f123/

All of them are redirected to `www.mydomain.com/somfile.php?f=123` with `RedirectRule` in Apache main conf file, everything works perfectly with my browser, no error output in Apache log file either.  However Apache logs the following errors every minute:

```
File does not exist: /home/mydomain/www/f123
```

What does this error mean and why is it thrown?

Comment: What do you get if you request `http://1.2.3.4/f123` where `1.2.3.4` is your IP address?

Comment: It's also redirected to www.mydomain.com/somfile.php?f=123 without any error output. It's always working well no matter what I try with browser.  
  
I also see the following errors:  
File does not exist: /home/natmed/mydomain/f123, referer: http://www.mydomain.com/f123/

Answer (score 1):

I know this sounds dumb but does the file really exist at that location (/home/mydomain/www/f123)? If you are using a masking technique like this and the file exists elsewhere then Apache won't actually find the file if it doesn't exist in the first place.

Additionally, I was thinking it may be permissions related. Perhaps it could have something to do with the executable permission, which is used to read directories and sometimes files in certain cases. Take a look at the permissions, make sure you can access as apache (user / group).

Usually path or permission 9 out of 10 times.

Comment: /home/mydomain/www/f123 doesn't exist, but /home/mydomain/www/somfile.php exists, the redirection works well. Basically, the website works perfectly for me and other several thousands visitors a day, but the Apache log suggests it doesn't work for some users. But I couldn't figure out how possibly the error was thrown out, because it's always working well when I test from my browser.

Comment: Right, thats why apache is complaining. Apache thinks that the literal file /home/mydomain/www/f123 exists, when it doesn't. It might be because of how your front-end users access the file as well. Take a look in apache's access logs for some clue.